# Query to find transactions which has taken place in 15 mins with different amount

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this scenario where I need to find out the transactions which happened in 15 minutes in my transaction detail table and also with different amount. 
For example transaction T1 (very first record) happened at 6.50 and T2 at 6.55 then both should come, because amount is different.

Second case if both the transactions are not happened within 15 minutes or if they happened within 15 minutes but the amount is same then exclude that record.

Below are the sample of record and expected result:

```
transid         transdate              TransAmount
T1              11/7/2016 6:50          400
T2              11/7/2016 6:55          450
T3              11/7/2016 7:15          300
T4              11/7/2016 7:31          300
T5              11/7/2016 7:50          500
T6              11/7/2016 7:55          600
```

Expected result: (record within 15 minutes and also with different amount)

```
transid         transdate              TransAmount
T1              11/7/2016 6:50          400
T2              11/7/2016 6:55          450
T5              11/7/2016 7:50          500
T6              11/7/2016 7:55          600
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: And pls ask a question as well because atm your post only describes your requirements, but fails to ask a single question. Some demonstration of your own efforts would also help

Answer (score 0):

this is for MS SQL SERVER, I calculated time difference in seconds, e.g 15 * 60 seconds = 60 mins.

for each record, use exists to find if a record matching your criteria is present or not

```
SELECT T1.* FROM transactions T1 WHERE 
        EXISTS (
                SELECT 0 FROM transactions T2 
                        WHERE 
                            ABS(DATEDIFF(second, T1.Transdate,T2.Transdate)) <= 15 *60 
                            AND 
                            T1.transAmount <> T2.Transamount
                )
```